# Check graph planarity using Kuratowski's theorem - C#

Tags: c#, graph, graph-theory

I want to check the planarity of a graph using the Kuratowski's theorem.

The idea I've got so far is that the best way to do this is by comparing the adjacency matrix of the input graph with both K5 and K3,3 adjacency matrices:

```
public int kuratowskiAut(Grafo g)
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[g.n.Count, g.n.Count];
        matrix = g.matrizAdyacencia;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;

        /*compare the two matrices
          for(int i = 0; i < g.n.Count; i++)
          {
                for(int j = 0; i < g.n.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(matrix[i, j] == adjK5[i, j])  // comparing to K 5
                    {
                        count1++;
                    }
                }
          }

          if(count1 == 25)
          {
                return 1; // Is non-planar
          }
          else
          {
                for(int i = 0; i < g.n.Count; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < g.n.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if(matrix[i,j] == adjK33[i,j]) //Comparing to K 3,3
                        {
                            count2++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(count2 == 36)
                {
                    return 1; // Is non-planar
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0; // Is planar
                }
          }
        */
        return 0;
    }
```

Also, I know that a way to check if the graph is non-planar is that I need to "transform" the input graph doing a series of operarions involving: deleting links between nodes, combining two nodes into one or inserting new nodes between two nodes.

Is there a way that I can do this? Or there's a better way to check if the graph is non-planar using this teorem?

Any help wold be aprecciated